# Context Free Grammar : Kleene plus

Tags: grammar

I make natural number set with context free grammar.

```
N ::= 0
 | 1  
 | 2 
 | 3 
 | 4 
 | 5 
 | 6 
 | 7 
 | 8 
 | 9 
 | kleene{...} plus
```

how can I express natural number, without kleene plus?

For example 1495

Answer (score 2):

You could express a natural number recursively.

```
N ::= N | N N
```

For 1495, 1 would be a natural number followed by another natural number (4), 4 would be a natural number followed by another (9), and 9 would be a natural number followed by a single natural number (5).

Answer (score 0):

```
DIGIT ::= 0 | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9
N ::= DIGIT | DIGIT N
```